# Tsql:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Tags: sql, t-sql

I get an error message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. I need the CTE in the later IF statement. Can anyone know how to resolve it? Thanks!
The code is below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION A
    (
        @CLT_NBR int,
        @YES OR NO varchar(10)

    )
    RETURNS datetime
    AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @EFFECT_DT date;

        WITH EFFECT_DT
        AS
        (
            SELECT CLT_NBR,
                EFFECT_DT,
                RN 
            FROM S
        )

        IF @YES_OR_NO='YES'
        BEGIN
            SELECT @EFFECT_DT=EFFECT_DT 
            FROM EFFECT_DT
            WHERE RN=2
            RETURN (@EFFECT_DT)
        END
        ELSE IF @YES_OR_NO='NO'
        BEGIN
            SELECT @EFFECT_DT=EFFECT_DT 
            FROM EFFECT_DT
            WHERE RN=3
            RETURN (@EFFECT_DT)
        END

    END
    GO
```

Comment: I change the SQL above. I will need the CTE in IF-else Statement.

Comment: You can't do that. The SELECT must immediately follow the CTE definition.  Put your IF into a CASE statement, with only ONE select, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) in the context where it will be used.

```
IF @YES_OR_NO='YES'
BEGIN;
  ;WITH EFFECT_DT AS (
    ...
  )
    SELECT @EFFECT_DT=EFFECT_DT 
    FROM EFFECT_DT
    RETURN (@EFFECT_DT)
END;
```

---

For your updated question, correcting the scalar udf:

```
alter function A (@CLT_NBR int, @YES_OR_NO varchar(10)) returns datetime as
begin;
  declare @EFFECT_DT date;
  with EFFECT_DT as (
  select 
      CLT_NBR
    , EFFECT_DT
    , RN
  from S
  ) 
  select @EFFECT_DT = EFFECT_DT
  from EFFECT_DT
  where (RN = 2 and @YES_OR_NO = 'YES')
     or (RN = 3 and @YES_OR_NO = 'NO')
  return (@EFFECT_DT);
end;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

`WITH` is part of the `SELECT` statement.  `IF` is a separate statement, so they are in the wrong order:

```
IF @YES_OR_NO='YES'
BEGIN
    WITH EFFECT_DT AS (
        ...
    )
    SELECT @EFFECT_DT=EFFECT_DT 
    FROM EFFECT_DT
    RETURN (@EFFECT_DT)
END;
```

If you want a "CTE" that spans multiple statements, then use a table variable or temporary table.  `WITH` is for only one statement.

Comment: Can you give more details?